# "Get event happening now" type problem in Redis

Tags: time, redis, calendar, ioredis

I'm building a system similar to a calendar, with events with start and end times. These can be UNIX timestamps. I want to be able to use a current UNIX timestamp and determine if an event is happening right now, and retrieve information on that event (the information about the event would be in a hash).

How should I go about this? I'm happy to use any key type.